# Not working with BorderLayout position JButton

Tags: java, jframe

I hava an `JButton` and want to position to the bottom left of an `JPanel`. This is my code:

```
    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 300));
    panel.add(jlabel1);
    panel.add(jlabel2);
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Later in the code, I update the `Jlabels` (if it matters):

```
    panel.remove(jlabel1);
    panel.remove(jlabel2);
//Some other code
panel.add(jlabel1)
panel.add(jlabel2)
```

Through all this, I want the JButton to stay in the bottom of the JPanel. How can I fix this? Nothing happens with the `BorderLayout.SOUTH`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that `BorderLayout.SOUTH` isn't doing anything because the panel to which you are adding `button` doesn't have a `BorderLayout`.

Check out the Java Tutorials section on layout managers for a better explanation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Meanwhile, this code (made up on-the-spot and completely untested) should give you some ideas about the direction you need to go:

```
panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 300));
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
buttonPanel.add(button);
panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JPanel labelPanel = newJPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
labelPanel.add(jLabel1);
labelPanel.add(jLabel2);
panel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!